# How can I change or install screensavers?

Tags: screensaver

I want to change the default screen saver in Ubuntu 11.10/12.04. On 11.04 I just did a

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod
```

And then I could change it in the *control center -> screen saver options*.

Now there seems to be no other option to change the default screen saver.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### Background

The Gnome 3 Devs dumped the old `gnome-screensaver`.  The replacement screensaver is just a blank screen.

The Canonical Devs thought it was a useful idea to continue and raised a [blue-print](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-screensaver) for implementation in Oneiric.

A few ideas were raised such as a Compiz specific implementation or reusing a Lubuntu/Xubuntu screensaver implementation.

However, at the time of writing, no implementation has been started.

### XScreenSaver

**installation**

Potential workaround - installing *xscreensaver*

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

Now remove gnome-screensaver

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Now start the xscreensaver configuration tool - from a terminal:

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

or search from the Dash:

[image]

Click *OK* to both prompts asking to turn-off Gnome Daemon and to start xscreensaver-daemon respectively.

[image: dash search]

**starting xscreensaver from login**

Now to start the xscreensaver daemon on login you need to search in *Dash* for *startup applications*

Create a new entry running the command `xscreensaver -nosplash`

**Locking the screen**

If you want to manually lock the screen with the keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then you will need to run the following to repoint the old gnome-screensaver lock to xscreensaver

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command
```

Logout or reboot for all changes to take effect.

Comment: This works great for me :) ... thanks for the help i now got the good old bsod again

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once....

Comment: This works in 13.05. :)

Comment: I recommend also Really Slick Screen Savers sudo apt-get install rss-glx

Comment: For 14.10 this doesn't work :(

Comment: What's the command name of the GUI on the screenshoot? `screensaver` says «command not found», and `xscreensaver` is just a command line tool.

Comment: This works but it even shows the screensaver when I watch a movie on the browser. I don't want that! What should I do to make it show screensaver only when I'm not having anything going on?

Answer (score 10):

> Ubuntu 11.10 doesn’t come with
>   [screensaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screensaver) package installed. You must install xscreensaver if
>   you want screensavers activated when your computer becomes idled.

1. `sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver`
2. `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra`
   [image]

**Links**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screensaver
2. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860551
3. http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/enable-screensavers-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/
4. http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/enable-screensavers-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

**Disclaimer**

*Above method works in 11.10 ,i didn't tried in 12.04*

Comment: Tried it on 12.04 and i works like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

Please take note that, for Ubuntu 12.04 and in order to be able to run several screensavers using images from the harddisk (e.g., Carousel, Gleidescope, GLSlideshow, Jigsaw, or XAnalogTV) , I had to install some additional packages.

These are:

- `libxss-dev`
- `libxss1-dbg`
- `libxss1`
- `kdelibs-bin`
- `kdelibs5-data`
- `kdelibs5-plugin`

Many others might get installed automatically together with the ones listed, particularly KDE libraries.

I found the instructions in [this blog](http://a1.blogspot.com/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-explained-setting-up.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you `sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver` but then `sudo apt-get install rss-glx` (see [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11990996#post11990996) and [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11991287#post11991287)), the Really Slick Screensaver (GLX) effects will run on top of a screen that has not been blanked under Unity in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, not just in xscreensaver-demo but also when the real screensaver kicks in.

Hence, a solution is required that does (even in the absence of gnome-screensaver) blank the screen prior to running the xscreensaver (which does work fine under LXDE for one thing).

Answer (score 0):

There is no screensaver by default in Ubuntu. You can install xscreensaver from the archives.

I'm not entirely sure screensavers actually do save screens anymore, though I'm inclined to think they don't. But they do consume large amounts of energy that could be better used for other things.

Comment: They prevent image burn-in on LCDs. And the amount of energy consumed by CPU is less than what Flash applets in a browser consume during normal day.

Comment: Switching off a monitor is a more efficient way to save both energy and the screen, wouldn't you say? This wasn't always possible.

Comment: Indeed. Though, there's a corner case - I don't want to warm up the monitor every time I'm away for less than 10 minutes, but would like it to auto-lock my screen. Blank screen is still there in Gnome, and why not replacing it with some fun pictures.

Comment: It encourages people to not power down their monitors, is one answer.