# How can I change my screensaver in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change or install screen savers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screen-savers)

I'm a new user of Ubuntu Oneric. Where can I set the configuration of my screensaver? I need to use Xscreensaver? What is the function of gnome-screensaver?

Comment: I do not think you can have a screensaver. I think the gnome-devs have removed it in Gnome 3..I am not sure. Also there are no options for changing it and also the default is just a blank screen.