# Is there an alternative to the default lock-screen?

Tags: lock-screen

I have a tablet PC that I'm running oneric on. One thing I don't like is that the default lock screen requires you to enter a password. Since this is a tablet, this means that it either needs to be connected to a keyboard, or I have to figure out how to get onboard to show up for the lock screen (caribou wont even start, and gok is messed up too). Even if I could do that, anyway, it's not what I want, since locking the screen is mostly to prevent erroneous input when I'm carrying it around (not for security).

Are there any alternative applications for the lock screen? Anything like the plethora of android lock screens that allow you to solve puzzles or push a particular widget in a particular way to unlock the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable the password input if that 'd help - go to system settings > screen > and change "lock". The screen then simply switches on without requiring you to enter your password.

Comment: Thanks, but then the lock screen doesn't lock the screen from touch input. I'd like a kind of application which just helps to prevent extraneous touch input while I'm waking around. Right now I'm doing this by running a script which just actually disables touch through xinput. I just thought it would be cool to have a smartphone-like lock screen

Answer (score 1):

The following question on AskUbuntu helped in my case:

[How do I turn off the onscreen keyboard on the lock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104341/how-do-i-turn-off-the-onscreen-keyboard-on-the-lock-screen/216502#216502)

Except you're presumably turning it on, but worth posting in case this was your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You could try xscreensaver (see [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers))

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

Now remove gnome-screensaver

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Now start the xscreensaver configuration tool - from a terminal:

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

there you can enter the time until screen-lock.

Comment: how would this help?

Comment: The xscreensaver actually manages screen locking since the screensaver requires a password in order to return you to the desktop.  I don't suggesting using xscreensaver since it's ancient...but it does work.

You should look at the answer provided here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75692/lock-screen-when-xscreensaver-was-installed

He says to execute this command so that you can press the keyboard combination CTRL+ALT+L to turn on the xscreensaver:

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command

Comment: This is not the problem - I think the user does *want* to enter a password. Please consider editing your answer to be relevant. Thanks :)

Comment: no, he doesen't want to enter a password, as he stated in the question: "locking the screen is mostly to prevent erroneous input when I'm carrying it around (not for security)"