# Lock screen when XScreenSaver is installed

Tags: 11.10, screensaver, lock-screen

I'm another user who dislikes the default screen-saver of Oneric.

I installed XScreenSaver, but when I want to lock the screen, it doesn't work using CTRL+ALT+L , or using the option on the user menu.

How can I get the locking behavior to work properly?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to manually lock the screen with the keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then you will need to run the following to repoint the old gnome-screensaver lock to xscreensaver

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screen-savers)