# Screen not locked after switching users with xscreensaver installed

Tags: screensaver, lock-screen, xscreensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock screen when XScreenSaver was installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75692/lock-screen-when-xscreensaver-was-installed)

I wanted some screensaver in addition to the default screen blanking. I installed xscreensaver from the SoftwareCenter & deinstalled gnome-screensaver using apt-get remove.
Most of it works fine but if I switch to user guest, the session of the account proper is no longer locked. I want this to be locked automatically in the same way as in gnome-screensaver.

Any idea?