# How to alias one command to be resolved into another command?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, lock-screen, screensaver

AFAIK `alias` is usually used to make 'shortcut' for long command. But what to do if I want to alias one command to another?

I need this because I replaced `gnome-screensaver` with `xscreensaver`, so the lock screen button does not work.

How to alias `gnome-screensaver-command -l` to be resolved into `xscreensaver-command -lock`?

Comment: I expect you're using Unity but in XFCE the lock function is handled by /usr/bin/xflock4. That's a script you can edit to prioritize gnome-screensaver or xscreensaver (or others). I don't know if it exists in Unity systems but something similar must.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, but in Unity there is no `xflock4`.  changed my question to be more relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: @Danatela - duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/75692/lock-screen-when-xscreensaver-is-installed?rq=1

Comment: @fossfreedom no, `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command` doesn't work.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @fossfreedom 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. I had to create such shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    -l)
        xscreensaver-command -lock
        ;;
    *)
        xscreensaver-command "$@"
        ;;
esac
```

Saved it as `/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command` and added execute permission:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command
```

Now, executing `gnome-screensaver-command -l` launches `xscreensaver-command -lock` and locks my screen.