# How do I turn off the onscreen keyboard on the lock screen?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, keyboard, lock-screen, accessibility

The lock screen has an on screen keyboard that I am unable to disable. I don't remember exactly but I believe I turned it on using the "Screen Keyboard" setting in the Universal Access settings. I've tried a number of things all with no effect:

- Toggling "Screen Keyboard" in Universal Access
- Toggling "Onscreen keyboard" in the login screen (LightDM)
- Clicking on the "x" in the upper right corner of the keyboard