# Change lock screen to the current wallpaper?

Tags: 11.10, screen, desktop-background, lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

When I lock Ubuntu 11.10, but before I unlock it, the screen is black. Is there any way to change the black background to, say, a current wallpaper?

It would be nice to see a wallpaper while the system is locked. Much more pleasing to the the eyes!