# Screensaver Settings

Tags: 11.10, settings, screensaver

**Hello, world.**

I recently installed ubuntu 11.10. I had been using 10:10, and did a reinstall to start fresh on this new version. The thing is I encountered myself with more than a few diferences, mostly in settings.

Now I can't seem to find the means to configuring my screensaver. ¿Where are screensaver settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change or install screensavers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

Comment: As you have probably noticed, there is no default way to change the screen-saver without a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 11.10 screensavers are disabled.

You can install it by typing into the terminal (`Ctrl + Shift + T`)

> sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver

Then also run:

> sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra

You should be able to access the screensaver by `Alt + F2` and typing `xscreensaver`

If you want the screensaver to run at startup, add it to **Startup applications**.