# How do I stop sound from muting when the screen is locked?

Tags: gnome-screensaver

How to change the settings to the screen locker not to mute the sound while the screen is locked?

Comment: I've seen posts asking for a way to actually mute the sound when the screen gets locked but not the other way around. It might help if you give more info.

Comment: Just a question about your hardware, are the speakers built into the monitor? Mine are and the sound stops because the monitor is going to sleep, thus cutting the power to the speakers. Ubuntu will not be able to control this.

Comment: I concur with @ChrisCarter. This must be a hardware problem.

Comment: I think that the questioner is talking about how to unmute the sound when screen is locked...?

Answer (score 2):

This will send the unmute command when the screen is locked, which **might** work. It will definitely work (tested) if what you want to do is just to unmute the sound when the screen is locked.

You can use Cuttlefish:

[image: Install via the software center]

Cuttlefish is a tool that lets you do everything you want to under specific circumstances, like while locking your screen. Please see an introduction to Cuttlefish (it is very easy to use, but it would still be a lot easier with a video as an example): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7mSfh9pqpg

So, you generally have to

1. Create a new Reflex and give it a name that you prefer
2. Click on 'Activated by stimulus'
3. Check as stimulus the 'Screen is locked' (under Screensaver header)
4. Go to the Reaction tab and add a new reaction from bottom left
5. Go to Applications->Start application (advanced mode)->OK
6. Click on the 'executable' which is by default firefox and alter it to `/usr/bin/amixer` (head to /usr/bin and select `amixer`
7. At the parameters below add `set 'Master' unmute`

Tested and works fine under Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install another screensaver alternative that could have another effect on your hardware:
see [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

Potential workaround - installing xscreensaver

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

Now remove gnome-screensaver

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Now start the xscreensaver configuration tool - from a terminal:

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

there you can enter the time until screen-lock.