# ubuntu does not have screensaver on unity

Tags: unity, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

on display settings on unity in brightness and lock does not show up the screensaver or does not have that option.

am i not seen it right or unity does not display screensaver like in kde or gnome?

i am using ubuntu 12.04 beta

however running a command Electric sheep  shows up in mplayer , but running gnome-screensaver or gnome-screensaver-command nothing happens..

do i have to install xscreensaver package?

or unity does not give screensaver at this time at all?