# How do I change the length of time the lock screen appears for?

Tags: lock-screen

When my screen is locked and I then reawaken it, by moving the mouse or pressing the keyboard, the password entry screen appears. How can I change the amount of time that is taken before the password entry screen turns off?

To be specific:

- I lock my screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Screen goes blank
- Move mouse to bring up login screen
- If I do nothing else the screen turns off again after 1 minute

In my Brightness and Lock settings I have the screen set to turn off and lock after 10 minutes, but I can't see a setting to determine how long it takes for the screen to turn off after the lock screen has been woken. It seems to be set to 1 minute by default, can this be increased/reduced?

[image]

Comment: May I know why do you want to change that option?

Comment: I am about to go back to 13. I can't find a way to keep the machine from locking itself about every ten minutes. I am so over it.

Comment: Not sure but this might be some of your help [ How to adjust screen lock settings on Linux desktop ](http://xmodulo.com/control-screen-lock-settings-linux-desktop.html) You might need to install **dconf-editor**

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, May I answer for the asker? For example, when you work in two environments in one computer - Windows as a host machine and Ubuntu in VM. So sometimes Ubuntu locks your session when it is not desirable.

Comment: A maximum of 15 minutes before the screen blanks isn't a very long time. Would really like to see a 30 minutes or even 60 minute option. It's very annoying when the screen begins to blank in the middle of a video.

Comment: I couldn't agree more to Matt's comment. In 2019, still. I don't want to have to unlock every time I leave my computer for 15 minutes (maximum allowed time in settings), so I end up disabling this feature completely and unnecessarily. Why not leave a little more choice to the user?

Answer (score 15):

#### Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier (Unity)

Open *System Settings*, click *Brightness & Lock* and select a value for the screen turn off option, *Turn screen off when inactive for*:

[image: screenshot]

Choose your time delay in the drop-down menu.

#### Ubuntu 17.10+ (Gnome Shell)

Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042641/349837).

Comment: this doesn't affect the length of time that the password entry screen appears for

Comment: How do I open System Settings? Can I script such a change with `dconf`?

Comment: You didn't understand the question.  The user wants to change the screen blank timeout for the gdm lock screen, which runs as the root user.

Answer (score 8):

You can not do that anymore in Gnome3.

In gnome2 you can change lock-screen timeout from gnome-screensaver settings.But  In Gnome 3.2, gnome-screensaver doesn't exist, and screen locking is part of Gnome Shell.

They have reimplement some function, but not all. On Ubuntu you can access all power-related settings with `dconf-editor` from `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`.

OR

You can use x-screensaver as described here:

[How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

Comment: This answer may be right on 2013, [now is possible](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042685/349837).

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem but could not resolve the issue with the answer provided by Kurshid Alam. On Gnome 3.28 using `dconf-editor`:

The screen saver turns on automatically when the session is considered idle

> org . gnome . desktop . screensaver . idle-activation-enabled

The easiest way to delay the screensaver is to increase the time limit for idle

> org . gnome . desktop . session . idle-delay

Or using terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay $((15*60)) && \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 0 && \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

Beware of possible impacts on laptop battery charge due to other services affected by the idle status.

Comment: duplicated question/answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042641/how-to-set-custom-lock-screen-time-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 4):

Settings -> Power -> disable *dim screen when inactive* & set *blank screen* to **never**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may answer the question it is not quite clear what this setting does exactly. Please elaborate your answer adding explanations.

Answer (score -3):

Press the windows button to get the unity search, then type lock in the search bar.
Open brightness and lock and change the timeout.

Comment: this doesn't affect the length of time that the password entry screen appears for