# How to set custom lock screen time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, configuration, lock-screen, gnome-shell

The maximum lock time in Ubuntu 18.04, when set via GUI, is 15 minutes. This can be set in *Settings* → *Power* → *Power Saving* → *Blank screen*.

I'd like to increase this to 30 minutes for my machine at home. How can I do that?

Comment: Related, for system admins to override and lock down settings like this: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-lockscreen.html.en and https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en.

Comment: Yeah it's ridiculous that it's 15 mins to never, like, nothing in between is an option.

Comment: Instead of `Settings > Power > ...`, got to `Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock`, as described by Nicolai [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047076). On 20.04 you'll see select boxes for both *"Blank Screen Delay"* and *"Automatic Screen Lock Delay"*. Although the options are still very limited, this does allow you to set e.g. a 30 minute or 1 hour delay until the screen actually locks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work @Nicolai. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Open Terminal and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1800
```

to set the "Blank screen" delay to 30 minutes or 1800 seconds (or set any value in seconds). You can use `$((30*60))` to use minutes directly.

**Note:** After making the change, in *Settings* → *Power* → *Power Saving* → *Blank screen* it will show "Never" as there is no entry for 30 minutes.

**To lock**: The number of seconds after blank screen activation before locking the screen (default: 0)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 0
```

**Needed**: Set this to TRUE (default) to lock the screen when the blank screen goes active

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

Comment: there must be a way to define those picklist choices such that updated list will appear on UI afterwards

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 by specifing a new value in terminal the new 30 minutes option is automatically created for you in UI

Comment: 7200 seconds is ideal since at home if I'm away longer than that I'm probably done for the day.

Comment: to `get` current `idle-delay`: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay`

Comment: You only described about lock screen/dim screen. What about auto-suspend? The UI settings only allows 2 hours until suspend. How can I manually maximize it like you said about lock screen timeout?

Answer (score 36):

The timeout for locking the screen after it goes blank can be achieved via GUI.

When using Ubuntu 18.04 open *Settings*. There select the *Privacy* settings tab. Now the *Screen Lock* option will be visible. When clicked, a modal window with the specific settings will open.

There you can toggle *Automatic Screen Lock* on/off, set a time for locking the screen or respectively binding it to the screen turning off via *Lock screen after blank for*, last but not least *Show Notifications* lets you decide if notifications should be shown on the lock screen.

So the path for the option you want to change is:
*Settings → Privacy → Screen Lock → Lock screen after blank for*
There you can select *30 minutes* as the lock screen time.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hmm... not sure whether it's the same thing. OP is asking for an option to change *Blank screen* delay, i.e. duration of inactivity that will turn screen off, whereas the settings you have mentioned is for "*Lock screen after blank for*" which I reckon means *after* the screen is off, how long the system will wait before *locking* the screen so that you'll have to provide your password on waking up.

Comment: Well he said maximum lock time, which can be set to more then 15 minutes via GUI. That's all I pointed out, if not for the OP, it might be helpful to somebody. @pomsky

Comment: There is no Privacy tab or choice in my Settings panel in 18.04.

Comment: @42- It is there for me, so I don't know what to say. Might be called privacy settings or so, I'm not running it in English. Take a look at the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/privacy.html.en).

Comment: This answer is useful but what I was looking for is to immediately lock screen after blank – `lock-delay 0` – and keep screen on for 30 minutes, or some other time, before the blank screen – `idle-delay 1800`; basically @pomsky 's answer. (This allows me to read from the screen during those 30 minutes.)

Comment: Everyone has different demands, we offered two options for anyone searching, which is good. @Daniel

Comment: I was wondering why the screen was locked after that 15 minutes screen blanking. The time is too short for my home PC to auto lock after such a short period. But the privacy section explains why.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 you'll see select boxes for both *"Blank Screen Delay"* and *"Automatic Screen Lock Delay"*. Might be worth updating the image above.

Answer (score 21):

There are **2 different settings**, one for blank screen and second for locking screen after blank.

#### 1. Set timeout of "Blank Screen"

- In GUI: *Settings* → *Power* → *Power Saving* → *Blank screen*
- In Terminal:

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1800
  ```

to set the "Blank screen" delay to 30 minutes or 1800 seconds (or set any value in seconds).

**Note:** After making the change, in *Settings GUI editor* it will show "Never" as there is no entry for 30 minutes.

#### 2. Set timeout of **"Lock screen after blank"**

- In GUI: *Settings* → *Privacy* → *Screen Lock* → *Automatic Screen Lock Delay*
- In Terminal:

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 600
  ```

to set the "Lock screen after blank for" delay to 10 minutes or 600 seconds (or set any value in seconds). **Set 0 to lock immediately after blank screen**.

#### To sum up

Combining these 2 parameters user is able to achieve for example:

- Blank screen after 10 minutes but lock after another 10 minutes (20 minutes overall to lock).
- Blank screen after 5 minutes and lock immediately.
- Blank screen after 30 minutes and lock after another 1 hour
- Any other combination depending on user's need.

Answer (score 2):

To set Blank Screen as "never" on Ubuntu 20.04, you should use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```