# Ubuntu 22.04-desktop-amd64 logout by it self

Tags: 22.04, logout

Im using ubuntu on a virtual machine, after 6 hours of opened session ubuntu automatically close it, and my opened programs too.In setings i put to dont close the session but it still closing.

[Here what i get after 6 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkdhF.png)

Comment: I think this is because this is the lock screen which if you leave the computer running someone could not do stuff look in the power management settings to change that

Comment: Also edit in Ubuntu flavor or desktop environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom lock screen time in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042641/how-to-set-custom-lock-screen-time-in-ubuntu-18-04)