# i install ubuntu 12.4 and i have no screen saver

Tags: screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

I install ubuntu 12.4 lts on my notebook acer AOD270, and i noticed that there is no icon under the Dash home for the screen saver, the only thing is a power management icon that sets the screen blank after a while, as far as i understand there should be a screen saver because i have seen videos for other notebooks with the same OS that DO have it,isn't something that should come with the installation? how can i get it? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you'll not find since there is by default anyway to get some screensaver just follow this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/). It's for 12.04 but i think it will work fine for 12.10

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME desktop used to use the package `gnome-screensaver` for screensavers.

The thing is, gnome-screensaver became not just responsible for screensavers, but also for the system lock screen.

In a possibly surprising twist of fate, it has now *removed* the screensavers!  So despite it still being called gnome-screensaver, all it does now is suspect/wake the screen and act as a lock screen.

Why remove screensavers?

- They work contrary to modern power saving, where the approach is to put the screen into sleep mode and let the CPU/GPU idle.  A screensaver *keeps the screen on* and *keep the CPU and/or GPU doing a small amount of work*.  This will use more power, generate more heat, etc.  This is particular important on battery powered devices like laptops and tablets.
- They don't really do all that much to save screens anymore.  Modern screens aren't really as susceptible to screen burn-in as older screens.  A lot of us now use screens at work for 8+ hours a day with taskbars, etc constantly visible, and yet it doesn't really cause much noticeable burn-in.

That said, some people still want screensavers for the same reason they've always wanted them - they look pretty (and they use a desktop or something where they don't care about energy use).

Thankfully the `xscreensaver` package still contains screensavers, though with some differences.  If you also install `xscreensaver-data-extra` and `xscreensaver-gl-extra` then you'll get even more screensaver options.  Once installed you can configure screensavers from the GUI (search for "screensaver").

Note however: this will effectively disable gnome-screensaver, so you will no longer see gnome-screensaver's lock screen but xscreensaver's lock screen, which will look and behave differently.

Comment: Thank you so very much, @neon_overload this is exactly what i need it to know, you rock!!!!