# Searching for the J. R. "Bob" Dobbs screensaver from Slackware to install in 13.10

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, enlightenment

I have seen on older (ca. 2004) RHEL systems a screensaver, *xlock*, with a twisting and morphing picture of J. R. "Bob" Dobbs. An extensive search of screensavers available for Ubuntu has not provided revelation. Does any SubGenius out there know where I may find it for the current Lubuntu?

Where do I expect to find it? Well, every screensaver app available via Synaptic and Ubuntu Software Center has been checked, to no avail, including [xscreensaver](https://vitux.com/how-to-replace-gnome-screensaver-with-xscreensaver-on-ubuntu/). I have also done an extensive search for it via multiple search engines, not merely looking at the first screen in a Google Search. That's why I am asking here.

How might I import that app from Slackware's repository into Lubuntu?

Comment: I suspect it is, or was, in `xscreensaver`.

Comment: According to [this man page for the xscreensaver `flag` hack](http://old.easyco.com/easydocs/linux/man/man1/flag.htm), you can get this with the `-bitmap '(default)'` option. `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver` should be what you want.

Comment: Looks like you are right @poolie , http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/screenshots/retired/ although it was removed in later versions.

Comment: All Hail Poolie! Would you put that in the form of an Answer so I may award you w/ a Chequemarque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on information from @poolie this screen saver used to be in `xscreensaver`, but is no longer. http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/screenshots/retired/ States that in version 5.08 the flag screen-saver was retired.

So to get it I dug up a [old version](http://www.rpm-find.net/linux/RPM/www.haoli.org/pub/redhat-5.2/RPMS/i386/outdated/xscreensaver-3.09-1.i386.html) and extracted it: http://ubuntuone.com/1VrIgyEQoBXJ6bR7JOly0O
Download `flag` from my link or extract it from the .rpm for the old version.

Then install `xscreensaver`  [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

Then in the same folder as you downloaded `flag` - navigate to it in terminal (you may need to mark it as executable):

```
./flag -bitmap "(default)"
```

This runs the screen-saver in a window:

[image: bob]

(note: might need to stop gnome-screensaver first, `sudo killall gnome-screensaver`)

---

Integrating with xsceensaver:

1. Copy `flag` to `/usr/lib/xscreensaver` (may need sudo permission)
2. run `xscreensaver` or `xscreensaver-demo`
3. Select any *existing* screensaver go to → Settings... → In the command line change to `flag -root`

[image: Settings]