# How to set up a screensaver in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, screensaver

I was wondering if there's any sort of package or something I could install in Ubuntu 13.10 to allow a graphical screensaver. I really do not like the blank black screen when the display turns off. I prefer abstract/colorful/exciting things over complete blackness. It reminds me of night which I think is bleak and boring. So any advice would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/a/64132/148826

Answer (score 0):

**Xscreensaver**

XScreenSaver is the standard screen saver collection shipped on most Linux and Unix systems

Installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

For extra screensaver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl-extra
```

You also need to replace genome-screensaver with xscreensaver. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=195557) is the article on how to replace it.