# Two lock screens when unlocking my computer

Tags: lock-screen

Probably I installed something, but I don't know what it is... Since then, I have to type my password twice in two different lock screens.

If I lock the computer (CTRL-ALT-L), then I have to give the password only once, in the default(?) Ubuntu lock screen (similar to [this one](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NJ0ByKWy98g/TzrWC2mRgtI/AAAAAAAACLM/YH8Xjv1v7Ls/s1600/New%20Lock%20Screen%20Ubuntu.png)).

However, if I close the lid, then I get two(!) lock screens. The first is something similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVYh8.png), and the second is the one I mentioned above.

Any idea why is it happening? How can I get rid of the first lock screen when I open the lid? I run Ubuntu 15.04.

#### Edit:

Here is the history of `apt-get install`:

```
    4  sudo apt-get install skype 
    7  sudo apt-get install google-chrome
   14  sudo apt-get install git
   28  sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext   libz-dev libssl-dev
   29  sudo apt-get install asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
   31  sudo apt-get install autoconf
   46  sudo apt-get install build-essential
   76  sudo apt-get install ack-grep
  150  sudo apt-get install python-pip
  187  sudo apt-get install virtualenv
  208  sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
  217  sudo apt-get install zmq
  218  sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
  219  sudo apt-get install zmq
  227  apt-get install python3-dev
  228  sudo apt-get install python3-dev
  230  apt-get update && apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip build-essential libzmq3-dev
  231  sudo apt-get update && apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip build-essential libzmq3-dev
  232  sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip build-essential libzmq3-dev
  237  sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
  272  sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
  289  sudo apt-get install spotify-client
  320  sudo apt-get install awesome
  325  sudo apt-get install workrave
  334  sudo apt-get install flyspell
  350  sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
  355  sudo apt-get install virtualbox
  360  sudo apt-get install virtualbox
  364  sudo apt-get install virtualbox
  367  sudo apt-get install virtualbox
  369  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
  379  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

BTW: if I disable the `Require my password when waking from suspend`, then I'm left only with one lock screen (the one from the second link).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24584/discussion-on-question-by-dror-two-lock-screens-when-unlocking-my-computer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What is extremely likely happening when you close your lid is the screen-saver kicking in.  Therefore:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

will solve your problem permanently after a reboot.

The `gnome-screensaver` is just an additional package that you remove (I'm running like this as well) and has no impact on your overall system (except that the screen-saver doesn't kick in, locking your computer after a period of inactivity).

If you use this computer for personal purposes, that's the only thing you've got to do!

If you use this computer for business purposes and still want a screen-saver that locks your screen automatically, you can still [install `xscreensaver`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers) from the software center (add the optional components for a ton of extra screen-savers).

Comment: This begs the question... what *else* can we remove from gnome once we're fully setup in MATE? Seems like it has extra stuff running that could be eating resources...

Answer (score 3):

I was able to remedy this by disabling the lock screen in the screensaver settings on my Ubuntu installation. I have MATE and gnome both installed; I think what happens is you get one MATE lock screen and one gnome lock screen; disabling the one within MATE leaves me with just one (admittedly nicer-looking) lock screen from gnome.

Answer (score 2):

Deactivate the screensaver via commandline:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -d
```