# There's multiple lockscreens/loginmanagers running at same time

Tags: login-screen, lock-screen

I installed Ubuntu Mate, then decided to `apt get install budgie-desktop`. Now I have both the GNOME/Budgie and Mate lockscreens. So when I login I have to type my password twice on both screens one after another. I don't want to remove the `budgie-desktop` I just want to disable the redundant lockscreens.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/633484/two-lock-screens-when-unlocking-my-computer